# Where to find my User Id

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, eventbrite

I'm trying to list down all user owned events in my app. The method for **User Owned Events** says i need **User Id** of the user to get retrieve all the user owned events. I can not see the **User Id** in my account over EventBrite. Can you please tell me where i can find this in EventBrite website ?

I do get the User Id from the parsed authentication as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Current i have manually created the request to get the response. I plan to make this automated, can you tell me the steps to get **User Id** from EventBrite. Are there any methods of **V3 API endpoint** that would return me the same, if i cant get it from EventBrite website ?

Awaiting replies.

Comment: Yes i have asked it on their forum as well. I asked it here on stack overflow since someone else might have faced the same problem and necessity. The number of people on stackoverflow is lot larger from the EventBrite forum on google group.

Comment: Response time on stackoverflow is also very quick. You can see that by yourself @JonP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checked with EventBrite Team, they say "instead of passing the UserId we can pass 'me' in the query string".

Example - **https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/owned_events**

Hope this helps !